# Yii Layout Error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 40961 bytes)

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

i am working on the yii framework and just making the different layouts for the different pages. I have created  a "login layout" for the login page so that i can design that page as per my requirements. I have just added a few lines of code on the layout file i.e login.php and code is here :

```
<?php 
/* @var $this Controller */
    $this->beginContent('//layouts/login');
        echo $content;
     $this->endContent();
?>
```

Now, i am using this layout on the UsersController's Login action. But as i set the layout of the action. Yii throws an error of such type which i have given below:

**Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 40961 bytes) in /home/teamreal/public_html/yii/framework/web/widgets/COutputProcessor.php
on line 33**

I have no idea why this error is being displayed again and again where as i have code the action function correcty which is as such:

```
public function actionLogin() {
        $this->layout = 'login';
        $model = new LoginForm('login');

        // if it is ajax validation request
        if (isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax'] === 'login-form') {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }

        // collect user input data
        if (isset($_POST['LoginForm'])) {
            $model->attributes = $_POST['LoginForm'];
            // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
            if ($model->validate() && $model->login())
                $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
        }
        // display the login form
        $this->render('login', array('model' => $model));
    }
```

So, please help me out to solve this problem.

Comment: You'll soon get a comment or answer on how to increase the memory limit. But 128 MB is already quite a lot. I guess you have an infinite loop or something similar.

Comment: Thank you Alvaro for your quick response. But i need to update you that i have not added any loop but after setting the layout it throws the error which i have posted on my question.

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean directly in your custom code. Sometimes, when using a framework, you can get such situations if you do something the framework did not expect. I only meant the increasing the memory limit is probably not the solution.

Comment: Install XDebug, so you will get stack trace for this error, will be easier to get to source of problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are decorating the `layout/login` over and over again with `layout/login`. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBaseController#beginContent-detail

Don't you want the main layout in `views/layouts/login`:

```
<?php 
  /* @var $this Controller */

  $this->beginContent('//layouts/main');
  echo $content;
  $this->endContent();
?>
```